# Getting the value of an input inside a td for each row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am still having so many problems with this:

```
function padTitles() {
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var tds = $(this).find('input'),

        text = tds.filter('[id^="TempRowKey_"]').val(),
        tdToPad = tds.filter('[id^="title_"]'),
        pad;
        if (/0\.0$/.test(text))
            pad = 10;
        else if (/\.0$/.test(text))
            pad = 35;
        else
            pad = 60;
        tdToPad.css('paddingLeft', pad);
    });
}
```

Note: here is what I was using before. This worked when the value was not inside an input:

```
var tds = $(this).find('td'),
text = tds.filter('[id^="refKey_"]').text(),
```

It is supposed to get the Value of the Inputs with id's that start with TempRowKey_  and then use these for padding. But the code does nothing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr id="row_1">
  <td id="tempRowKey_1" >
    <input type="text" size="10" value="1.0.0" class="updatable" id="TempRowKey_1">
  </td>
  <td id="title_1">
     <input id="Title_1" class="updatable" type="text" value="zxxx" size="100" name="item.Title">
  </td>.
  <td ...
</tr>
```

Is there some way I can test this. I can't get access to anything inside the jQuery block?

Update:

```
Here is my original code that worked before I enclosed the value I need inside an input:

function padTitles() {
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var tds = $(this).find('td'),
        text = tds.filter('[id^="refKey_"]').text(),
        tdToPad = tds.filter('[id^="title_"]'),
        pad;
        if (/0\.0$/.test(text))
            pad = 10;
        else if (/\.0$/.test(text))
            pad = 35;
        else
            pad = 60;
        tdToPad.css('paddingLeft', pad);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your variable naming makes no sense. You have a variable called `tds` that actually references a jQuery object containing `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

[This jsFiddle is working and achieves the functionality that you have outlined](http://jsfiddle.net/HpU88/1/)

Let me know if this is not what you want?

Comment: There's a check-arrow to the left, beneath the "0" and "down arrow". My karma would love if you clicked it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had to put a `<table id="mytable">` and change the selector to "#mytable tr" for it to work.

Also, tdToPad's title needs to be Title.

[**see the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cC6jT/2/)